# asp.net mvc2 Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes

So I have added this route to my map:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", 
        "/Bikes/{id}", 
        new { controller = "Bike", action = "Detail" }
    );
```

But for SEO reasons we need to have urls like: **/bikes/54**/name-of-bike/kind-of-bike/number-of-wheels ... etc etc. But everything after id (54) can be ignored.

Does anyone know how to create such a MapRoute to allow that, the route above does not work actually for urls that contain stuff after the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a catchall parameter like so

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "/Bikes/{id}/{*stuff}", 
    new { controller = "Bike", action = "Detail", stuff = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

then anything after id will be stored in stuff

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "/Bikes/{id}/{slug*}", 
    new { controller = "Bike", action = "Detail", 
          slug = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

Comment: You need to use `{*slug}` as yours isn't valid